# Swift - NSIndex forRow inSection Initializer

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

`var path = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection:0);`

and I get a compiler warning saying:

`Extra Argument 'inSection' in call`

Why? I see the initializer in the documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSIndexPath/indexPathForRow:inSection:

I imported UIKit, and even tried doing something like:

`var path = UIKit.NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection:0);`

What am I misunderstanding here?

EDIT:

```
var index = 0;

        for (key, value) in map! {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { (index) in
                //some code

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { (index) in
                    println("reloadRow row=" + String(index) + ",inSection:0");
                    var path = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection:0);
                    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([path], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);
                });
            });
            index++;
        }
```

Comment: How is `index` defined?

Comment: @MikeS its an integer. `var index = 0;` Hold on, let me post the whole code block, because maybe the way I am using closures has something to do with this.

Comment: @MikeS Okay, I have the full code now, perhaps I am not using closures correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`index` may not be recognized by the compiler. Try the code in playground:

```
import UIKit
let index = 3
var path = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
```

Works

```
import UIKit
var path = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
```

Error: `Extra Argument 'inSection' in call`

It means that your `index` variable is not well defined. Or you should try to `Clean` and delete the derived data.

Edit:
Remove the `index` declaration in your `dispatch_async` it conflicts with your `index` variable.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { _ in
                    println("reloadRow row=" + String(index) + ",inSection:0");
                    var path = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection:0);
                    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([path], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);
                });
```

Bonus: You should use Swift nice shortcuts with closures. (trailing closure + no parameters) as it:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
       println("reloadRow row=" + String(index) + ",inSection:0");
       var path = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection:0);
       self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([path], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);
    }
```

Edit:  you do the same mistake in the first dispatch async. When you declare a `dispatch_async` and you write `{ index in` it's the same thing as declaring a function with an index as a parameter. It's a variable scope issue (you should read about this). I update the final code.

```
    var index = 0
    for (key, value) in map! {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            //some code
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                println("reloadRow row=" + String(index) + ",inSection:0");
                var path = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection:0);
                self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([path], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);
            }
        }
        index++
    }
```

Comment: I think you are exactly right. I just put a more complete example up, does it have to do with how I am using closures?

Comment: So with your code I saw that you actually defined another variable called `index` within the `dispatch_async`. You don't have to do that, all variables in scope are accessible through closure.

Comment: So this does absolutely fix the compiler error. As a side note, do you know why the value of index is always the number of elements in my dictionary when using closures like this? I am familiar with Javascript closures which copy the current values of variables in scope, but that does not seem to the be the case with swift.

Comment: Because you do the same mistake in the first dispatch async. When you declare the `dispatch_async` and you do `{ index in` it's the same thing as declaring a function with an `index` as a parameter. It's a variable scope issue. I update the final code.

Answer (score 2):

To preserve the **current** `index` value in async blocks,
you should use [Closure Expression Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_156). It can be called immediately like this.

```
var index = 0

for (key, value) in map! {
    { (idx) in // <- this is fixed value `index`
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            // some code...
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                var path = NSIndexPath(forRow: idx, inSection:0);
                self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([path], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);
            }
        }
    }(index++)
}
```

---

The code in OP can be translated to JavaScript:

```
var index = 0;
while(...) {
  dispatch_async(GLOBAL_QUEUE, function(index) {            

    //some code

    dispatch_async(MAIN_QUEUE, function(index) {
      var path = new NSIndexPath(index, 0);
      self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([path], ANIM_AUTO);
    });
  });

  index++;
}
```

You see? Because `dispatch_async`'s callback doesn't receive any arguments, so your **inner** `index` will be `undefined`.

Instead, you should code like this:

```
var index = 0;
while(...) {
  (function(idx) {
    dispatch_async(GLOBAL_QUEUE, function() {            

      //some code

      dispatch_async(MAIN_QUEUE, function() {
        var path = new NSIndexPath(idx, 0);
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([path], ANIM_AUTO);
      });
    });
  })(index++);
}
```

I think, `(function(val){ ... })(val)` idiom is very common in JavaScript, isn't it?

Comment: Why is this different than what I was doing? Sorry, I am rather new to Swift, but I do understand Javascript closures quite well if you want to make some comparisons.

Comment: I don't understand why the inner anonymous function would not have access to the value of index when it was called.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you are trying to get across now. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Because `index` "variable name" is overwritten by an argument of callback function.

Comment: Thanks for your patience with my bad English skills :)

Comment: it did not even occur to me you were not a native english speaker, so I would say your English is very good!

Answer (score 1):

For me Xcode 8.3 and Swift 3 works like below:

```
  let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: row, section: section)
```